# menu bar only app, not responding

Tags: macos, swift, menuitem, menubar

What I am doing in the app is to have a while true loop to read from a file.

This is the code I wrote

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
// Insert code here to initialize your application
statusItem.title = "Stopped!";
while true
{
  println("Start While Loop");
  let path = "~/.pomodoro/log.txt";
  let expandedPath = path.stringByExpandingTildeInPath;
  var data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: expandedPath);
  var content:NSString?;

  sleep(30);

  if data != nil {
    content = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
  }

  var titleString = content! + " M";
  println("TitleString = \(titleString)");

  if (content == "0")
  {
    titleString = "Stopped";
  }

  statusItem.title = titleString;

  println("Loop One Stoped");


}
```

This is everything the program did. It just read from a file and change the menubar item title to that string. The string will always be a one - two digit number.

However, I don't know why every time I run the app the app stops responding.

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching` needs to return - it's part of the initialisation sequence, and if you don't return, the initialisation cycle will not complete (as you noticed). Spawn a thread or some other task to read your file.

Comment: ... and read this, which deprecates `applicationDidFinishLaunching` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. You are frizzing the main thread.

You don't let the app update and respond to events.
If you need to make an infinite loop do it in a background thread.
But in your case the best thing to do is to Make A ViewController and use NSTimer to update times to times the title.

Comment: Oh, That's why. Thank you very much for your help.